# What is the proper CSS selector to get what I need?

Tags: java, css, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm using a Java lib ([JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)) to fetch content from a website that my program can ingest and then process. Specifcally, the content I'm looking for is inside the `ontw` div below:

```
<div class="ms5">
    <div class="header">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="ontw">
            <!-- What I want is here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With JSoup, you download the page using `Document doc = JSoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get()`, and then you parse the contents of that page using `doc.select("Your CSS selector string here.");`. It's really that simple.

I tried:

```
doc.select("ms5 body ontw");
```

But that doesn't work. Judging by the HTML above, what should my CSS selector string be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes are selected with a dot, so you have to select `.md5 .body .ontw`

```
doc.select(".md5 .body .ontw");
```

Comment: Thanks @BackSlash (+1) - am I correct in assuming that if I just made it `doc.select(".ontw")` that I could be pulling back *any* HTML elements that are decorated with the `.ontw` class, and not necessarily the `.ontw` content that I want (under `ms5/body`)?

Comment: @TicketMonster You're welcome! Yes, you are right that would select _any_ element with the specified class, no matter what are its containers

Answer (score 1):

```
Element masthead = doc.select("div.ontw").first();// div with class=ontw
```

You can refer the JSoup Documentation:

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.select("div.ontw");
```

Would be what I would expect

Comment: Avoid overqualified selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ms5 .body .ontw
```

is what you want. Here is a demo: http://try.jsoup.org/~jAMCqcMjLMSA5FYJV7Cn3Aah4AE